# WebSocket connection failed ERROR on Production (React 18.2.0)

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I've got this error after building my project to a live server. It appears after 20-30 seconds after the page loads (any page).
Everything works just fine on my localhost.
[image: Error]

I tried to create .env file WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0 in the same folder with package.json but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you created the server but the problem here:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  // handling CORS
  cors: {
    origin: 'YOU SHOULD WRITE WEBSITE URL HERE',
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

the socket.io server will not accept any connection that his URL is not similar to the URL in the origin value

---

anything else will be in react connection, for example, you forgot to write the correct URL